# Making a variable accessible to any object

Tags: c#, scope

Lets say I have a loop that runs through a list of objects,

```
foreach( object pawn in objectList )
{
   pawn.update();
}
```

This runs all the update codes, right? Simple because you don't have to pass any information into the update function to make all the objects run.

How can you access this array of objects in one of the objects that are apart of the list? Or any object for that matter? Kind of like how you can always get members from the Console.

For example, I can retrieve a value like Console.BackgroundColor in any object. How can I do this with the objects list?

```
this.value = Console.BackgroundColor // You can access it directly from the class.
```

Comment: Mark the property or method as `static`.

Comment: Just that fixes the problem?

Comment: You mean making that object list public so it can be accessed from outside its class?  It should be public and static then so it is available even if you don't have an object of that class defined

Comment: @Rusty30 That's what I mean.

Comment: See edit on my previous comment. I can be more specific if you post more about the scope of the object list and where are you calling it from.

Comment: @Lemony-Andrew  stay away from static for this kind of stuff, see my answer for an alternative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

static public members of classes can be accessed

eg

```
public static class Blah 
{
   public static List<MyObject> Stuff = new List<MyObject>();
}
```

can be accessed from anywhere with `Blah.Stuff`;

HOWEVER.

This is generally a bad idea.  Most often if you adjust your design a bit, you don't need global access like this.  Its most useful for TRULY global resources.

For your situation you might want something like

```
   foreach( IChild pawn in objectList )
    {
       pawn.Parent = objectList;
       pawn.update();
    }
```

where

```
public interface IChild
{
   void update();
   List<IChild> Parent { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I really like how you're giving me ideas for work arounds.. But can we talk more about what you're doing here: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57885/work-around-scopes ?

Answer (score 3):

This deals with instance vs static methods. Console.BackgroundColor is a static property, so it's available everywhere. Your loop calls instance methods, so it can only call methods on instances it has a direct reference to.

I recommend that you read some more about static vs instance methods.

http://cplus.about.com/od/howtodothingsinc/a/An-Overview-Of-Static-and-Instance-In-C.htm

Comment: I've been having some bad experiences with them. Anyhow, from what I read everyone says avoid static..

Comment: There are pros and cons to both static and instance level. It all depends what you are trying to do.